# 2D Game Development Software that can release your game on Steam

Tags: 2d, game-design, steam

Im looking for a game development software that can also publish to steam, I know most can but some come with an additional fee and some without, I think the Cryengine allows you to publish to greenlight without having to pay the fee but for a simple 2D game I do not think cryengine is the way to go. 
Any advice? :)

Comment: To avoid being closed, you need to rephrase this. We don't know which is best for you because we are ourselves; answers are likely to be opinions and could be based on the creator's programming language preference or that they just don't like the default color scheme of the GUI. Explain how/why cryengine (or others) don't fit your needs and ask for alternatives. As a minimum, enumerate the specific needs you have that are making it difficult to decide.

Comment: I am unable to edit my question which sucks. Cryengine wont work as I feel it is to sophisticated for my needs, I am building a simple 2D box maze game: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=255194678&searchtext= with Game Maker but the problem is I would still have to pay an additional Fee to get the game onto Greenlight as well as buy the full version of Game Maker which is very expensive, so I am basically looking for a very simple game developer tool that is cheap and can be used to publish my game to Steam without having to pay so much money.

Comment: Making a game is mostly about creatively solving problems. If you manage to make a game good enough to get through greenlight, I'm sure you'll be able to get it on steam. Whether you made it with monogame, game maker, unity, unreal engine, cryengine, sdl, pygame, or any other way possible

Comment: You need to understand that Steam is a platform for professional game development companies to distribute their games, not for hobbyists. When you are doing this just for fun and want to reach a larger audience, then there are other channels you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't done any research so forgive me, but I'm pretty sure that, as long as you have the rights to commercially use the game engine or whatever you are using, than you will only need to pay the $100 for Greenlight access.

My advice is do a quick google search on the engine you are looking at using, add "commercial use" (gamemaker commercial use). You should find out pretty quickly if it is free for commercial use.

Some examples of game engines which are free for commercial use are:
(I know that you said that you feel that cryengine is too complicated so I will stay away from some of the larger engines like UE4 and Unity. Also I will focus on engines which focus on 2D games)
PlayN, Adventure Game Studio, Flexible Isometric Free Engine, and Cocos2d.

Another way to quickly find Game Engine licenses is to go to this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

Best of luck, and welcome to the Stack Exchange.

Comment: We are not a forum, we are a question&answer site.

Comment: i'll edit my answer to include some examples

Comment: Cronnoc understands my question :P Thanks, i will have a look at those engines.

Comment: Everyone understood your question, it just isn't appropriated to this site.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need any specific development software to release games on Steam Greenlight. Any game can be submitted to Steam Greenlight by creating a steam account, "buying" the [Greenlight Submission Fee](http://store.steampowered.com/app/219820) and then [uploading the game through the steam greenlight website](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/editgame/?appid=765). It's a one-time fee, so after paying it you can submit as many games as you want.

When you use a software where the fee is already included, you will be paying the fee indirectly by paying for the software. But seriously, 90€? That cost is barely the equivalent of two people-hours development time.

You won't find a way to get on Greenlight completely free of charge. The minuscule fee is an intentional barrier to only get people who are at least a bit serious about professional game development and prevent the complete amateurs from flooding the portal with junk. Valve isn't even doing it to make money: They donate any revenue from Greenlight sumission fees to [Child's Play](http://www.childsplaycharity.org/).

Comment: I think he/she is asking for free software

Comment: Yeah, Im only talking about the software, I am aware I can not get away with the Greenlight fee and I am not trying to do it free of charge lol. What I am asking is if anyone knows of a decent 2D engine which either has the superscription option like cryengine has or is not extremely expensive like game maker, when you convert to Zar its massively expensive.

Comment: @ABI7ITY How is GameMaker expensive? With $75 for the basic version it is on quite the lower end when it comes to game development tools. For comparison, Unity3d, the favorite choice for many low-budget independent developers, costs $1500 per license. The Cry engine is also more expensive than Game Maker. It costs $9.99 per month, and a serious game development project takes far more than just 7.5 person-months of development time. Anyway, what engine to use questions are off-topic here because they are too much based on personal opinion and preference.